# Gatling Build from Frontline Exception

Tags: gatling-plugin

Gatling Build is failing with exception:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   io.gatling.frontline:frontline-maven-plugin:1.0.3:package (default) on
>   project msg-service-prf: Execution default of goal
>   io.gatling.frontline:frontline-maven-plugin:1.0.3:package failed:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file -> [Help 1].

Same thing is working fine from local laptop.

Gatling version using: `3.3.1.`

More details on what I did:
Since, the existing Gatling support is not able providing support for multiple connections, we tried to extend it from Gatling code. As part of that, one scala Gatling source file is modified and tried testing it.

It worked fine in local laptop. But, I configured the TC in Frontline and started test, it went to Broken state. logs showing the above error.

What I did to resolve this:
1) excluded the Gatling jms jar in pom.xml. because, "gatling jms" source project is available for the targeted project as source. locally, it's not giving any issue.

If anyone of you come across such issue, please let me know how did you solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maven didn't properly download the frontline-maven-plugin jar and it ended up corrupted in the maven local cache on your FrontLine machine.
Please remove ~/.m2/repository/io/gatling/frontline/frontline-maven-plugin directory and try again.